# Calculate stock quantity

Tags: django

I have two models containing different types of transactions that i want to use as the base for calculation of quantities for my products, but I have a hard time making a query that works.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
...
   transaction_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, db_index=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1, db_index=True)
...

class TransactionItem(models.Model):
   transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   product = models.ForeignKey(product, on_delete=models.CASCADE related_name="product")
   stock_location = models.ForeignKey(warehouse_stock_locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Lagerplats", related_name="stock_location", blank=True, null=True)
   qty = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
   unit_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

so I want to collect the quantities in all transactions that have the `status "2"`, which is equal to a completed inventory count, goods delivery, while `status=1` and `status=3` are ignored. I'll then sum all qty in TransactionItems and display on the respective product detail pages. I've looked at various examples of queries, but they all lead me to an error.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems I solved it myself.

solution:

```
t = TransactionItem.objects.filter(transaction__status=2)
t = t.filter(product_number=self.object).aggregate(Sum('qty'))
t = t.get('qty__sum')
print(t)
```